# NginX: local IP vs. public IP

Tags: networking, nginx, proxy, ip, ip-address

Say I want to redirect a request to another computer **within the same local network**. I can use its private IP address or its public IP address. Will the private one achieve faster performance?

```
proxy_pass http://192.168.0.101; # Private IP
```

vs.

```
proxy_pass http://100.200.300.40; # Public IP
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a local network, I would just use the private IP address.  This would limit the nginx daemon to the local network and not open it to the world which could create security implementations directly on the machine.

There is a performance difference that you can see was answered under this question.  I can't estimate the difference as there are many variables that could lead to those performance differences.

https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20612/difference-in-latency-between-public-and-internal-ip-addresses